# Unable to append shape to svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Its printing id on dragstart event on the element(png image) however, shape is not getting appended to svg on dragend event.

```
window.onload = function ()
            {
                var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 800)
                        .attr("height", 803);
            };
            var shapeId = "";

            function getId(id)
            {
                shapeId = id;
                console.log(shapeId);
            }

            function createShape()
            {
                if (shapeId == 'newTask')
                {
                    createRect();
                }
            }

            function createRect() 
            {
                console.log("createRect function called");
                svg.append("rect")
                        .attr("id", "onRectDragStart")
                        .attr("rx", 10)
                        .attr("width", 51)
                        .attr("height", 41)
                        .attr("x", "100")
                        .attr("y", "100")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .classed("initialDragRect", true);
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
            <div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
            <div><a id="newTask" title="Add new task" draggable="true" ondragstart=getId(this.id) ondragend="createShape(this)"><img src="task.png" /></a></div>
   </div>
    <div id="canvas" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

`createRect()` function is being called as its printing message inside console but shape is not getting appended

`createShape(this)` is getting called inside div tag on dragend event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the scripts after DOM is loaded completely because you are interacting with the DOM using events.

Example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <head>
      <!-- yada yada yada -->
    </head>

    <body>
      <p id='p1'>Line 1</p>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write("<p>p1 is null? " + (document.getElementById('p1') == null ? "yes" : "no") + "</p>");
        document.write("<p>p2 is null? " + (document.getElementById('p2') == null ? "yes" : "no") + "</p>");
      </script>
      <p id='p2'>Line two</p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

The output you see is:

```
Line 1
p1 is null? false
p2 is null? true
Line 2
```

because p1 exists as of when the script runs, but p2 doesn't.

Check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E) by developers of google for more info. Help this helps

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the var `svg` to a svg correctly here:

`var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")`

but then you reasign it to the `body` element

`var svg = d3.select('body');`

Remove `var svg = d3.select('body');` and you should be able to append to your `svg` just find with: `svg.append("rect")`

Remeber that when you do: `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")`, the var `svg` holds the svg element you have appended to the `body`, not the `body` itself

**N.b.** Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La7wv2sd/) showing the minimum code to render the `svg` and `rect`, if your code still isnt working then it might be related to how you are calling the code and where/when you are calling the code. (which isnt included in the question)

Comment: when i remove `var svg = d3.select('body')` its throwing an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: svg is not defined`

Comment: added a jsfiddle showing min code required. you migh be having issues at the time/place you call your `createRect` function (i.e. has D3 loaded by then? is the dom loaded?)

Comment: It's as I suspected, you are calling `createShape` before it's defined (as you'll see from the errors in your jsfiddle). try loading your functions before your html, or put all your code in the document ready

Comment: Tried with document.ready(). Still the same issue. http://jsfiddle.net/0jmv4kfq/1/